# Одномерный массив(самая длинная возрастающая последовательность)

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Сама задача звучит так:
Найти максимально длинную возрастающую последовательность. Элементы не обязательно должны идти последовательно. E.g.: {9, 6, 2, 7, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8, 4} --> {2, 4, 6, 8}
Сам сидел думал дня 3 и ничего дельного в голову не идёт подскажите как делать такое может подход какой есть чтобы подступиться к задаче, а я ни сном ни духом.

Comment: Смотрите [Задача поиска наибольшей увеличивающейся подпоследовательности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). В статье есть алгоритм со сложностью O(n log(n)). В ответах Вам уже дали решения, но они за O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Ну есть решение на c++
вот

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int mas[1000];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> mas[i];
    int count[1000];
  count[0] = 1;
 
  for(int  i = 1; i < n; i++){
        count[i] = 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if(mas[i] > mas[j] && count[j] + 1 > count[i])
                count[i] ++;
        }
  }
  sort(count, count + n);
  cout << count[n - 1];
    return 0;
    }
```

1. Создаём массив для длин подпоследовательностей и заполняем его 1.
2. Пробегаемся по массиву с последовательностью со второго элемента и ищем элемент меньше него с максимальным значением во втором массиве, прибавляем к этому значению 1 и записываем во второй массив.
   3)Выводим максимальное значение из второго массива.

Comment: да у меня проблема такая что я сам хочу сделать, а не выходит,думал может есть какой подход к задаче

Comment: Я думал может делать типа идём циклом for и внутри ещё while и типа когда встречаем что от текущего появился элемент больший начинаем типа отсчитывать и следить за последовательностью, но там проблема что она может разрываться и тогда не работает

Comment: Ну мой алгоритм работает.

Comment: Переведите код на C# согласно тегу в вопросе.

Comment: @Vlad261280 Какая разница что алгоритм работает, если в тегах стоит другой язык? Представь, что тебе на вопрос по плюсах ответили кодом на питоне или брейнфаке аргументировав тем что код работает. Тебе от этого легче станет?)

Answer (score 1):

Первым алгоритмом мы заполняем массив mas[], потом создаем массив arr[] первый элемент которого равен единице, а остальные равны нулю. Потом опять идет цикл for(int i)который начинается с 1 и до конца, в нем есть еще один цикл for(int j) который идет с самого начала и до i. В нем мы проверяем если i-элемент, больше j-элемента, то во второй массив на j позицию добавляем единицу. Во время цикла запоминаем лучший результат и выводим его.

Comment: поподробнее можете расписать идею,а то я что-то сижу и не понимаю как оно работает, вижлы нет чтобы код протестить

Comment: При чем здесь C++?

Comment: c# не знаю так что расписал алгоритм как можно подробней.